# How to solve: lto1: fatal error: bytecode stream in file '...' generated with LTO version 6.0 instead of the expected 7.1

Tags: python, c++, gcc, lto

I am trying to embed a simple (test) Python script into C++. See this question for reference: [Undefined reference to `main` error when embedding Python in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64124725/undefined-reference-to-main-error-when-embedding-python-in-c) I'm trying to embed Python in C++. This is my Python file (with the name EmbedTest.py):

```py
from __future__ import division

class model:  
    def init(self,a,b):  
        self.a = a  
        self.b = b  
         def test_method(a,b):  
    m = model(a,b)  
    m.add(1)  
    print("a: ",a,"b: ",b)  
    return (a+b,a-b,a*b)
```

This is my C++ file (with the name EmbedTest.cpp and located in the same folder as EmbedTest.py)

```cpp
#include <Python.h>  

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc;  
    PyObject *pArgs, *pValue, *pValue_1, *pValue_2;  
    double sum,diff,prod;  
    double a = atof(argv[1]);  
    double b = atof(argv[2]);   
    Py_Initialize();  
    pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("EmbedTest.py");  
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);  
    Py_DECREF(pName);  

    if(pModule != NULL) {
      pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule,"test_method");    
      if(pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {  
          pArgs = PyTuple_New(2);  
          pValue_1 = PyFloat_FromDouble(a);  
          pValue_2 = PyFloat_FromDouble(b);  
          if (!pValue_1) {
          Py_DECREF(pArgs);
            Py_DECREF(pModule);
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
        return 1;  
        }  
        if (!pValue_2) {
        Py_DECREF(pArgs);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
        return 1;  
        }  
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue_1);  
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, pValue_2);  
        
        pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);  
            Py_DECREF(pArgs);  
            if (pValue != NULL) {
            sum = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyTuple_GetItem(pValue,0));
            diff = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyTuple_GetItem(pValue,1));
            prod = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyTuple_GetItem(pValue,2));  
              printf("a: %f b: %f sum: %f diff: %f prod: %f",a,b,sum,diff,prod);  
              Py_DECREF(pValue);  
            }  
            else {  
                Py_DECREF(pFunc);  
                Py_DECREF(pModule);  
                PyErr_Print();  
                fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");  
                return 1;  
            }       
          } else {  
              if (PyErr_Occurred())  
                PyErr_Print();  
              fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);  
          }  
          Py_XDECREF(pFunc);  
          Py_DECREF(pModule);  
        }  
        else {  
          PyErr_Print();  
          fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);  
          return 1;  
    }  
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {  
        return 120;  
    }  
    return 0;  }
```

I try to compile and link by running

```
gcc -c $(python3.8-config --cflags --embed) EmbedTest.cpp

gcc EmbedTest.o $(python3.8-config --embed --ldflags)
```

where `python3.8-config --cflags` expands to

```
-I/home/MyUserName/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -I/home/MyUserName/anaconda3/include/python3.8  -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O3 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/mbm/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/build/80754af9/python_1593706424329/work=/usr/local/src/conda/python-3.8.3 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/MyUserName/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -fuse-linker-plugin -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -flto -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O3 -Wall
```

and where `python3.8-config --ldflags` expands to

```
 python3.8-config --ldflags
-L/home/MyUserName/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/home/MyUserName/anaconda3/lib  -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lrt -lm -lm
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
lto1: fatal error: bytecode stream in file ‘/home/MyUserName/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.a’ generated with LTO version 6.0 instead of the expected 7.1
compilation terminated.
lto-wrapper: fatal error: gcc returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I understand this has to with the link-time-optimization and the fact that the python code appears to be compiled with an old vesion off gcc. My version of gcc is 8.3.0. To address this I tried to recompile but removing any extra flags (that have to do with LTO). So I tried

```
gcc -c -I/home/MyUserName/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -I/home/MyUserName/anaconda3/include/python3.8 EmbedTest.cpp
gcc EmbedTest.o $(python3.8-config --embed --ldflags)
```

but I get the same error message as before. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: What does it say if you pass `-fno-lto` to the linker command line?

Comment: @Botje Thank you very much! Compiling and linking now appears to work. When I try to run the program however, I get an error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'EmbedTest' Failed to load "1" ". However, I don't know if this error is due to the compiler.

Comment: You probably need to produce a shared library (.so) file instead of an object file: `gcc -fPIE -shared EmbedTest.o $(python3.8-config --embed --ldflags) -o libEmbedTest.so`. And that probably also needs the `-fPIE` option when you compile EmbedTest.o

Comment: @Botje Thanks for the suggestion. It appears I have to compile with the -fPIC flag. However, I don't seem to actually get an executable in the end.

Comment: Sorry. Brainfart. You should not compile as a shared library if you have a main function, of course. You may need to ensure that the directory hosting `EmbedTest.py` is on your Python `sys.path` first.

Comment: @Botje Ok, no problem. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Botje I added the directory using sys.path.append('/home/MyUserName/MyFolder'), where MyFolder contains EmbedTest.py (and also EmbedTest.cpp and the other files). However, I still get the same error message. Do you know if there's anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: Suggest you ask a follow-up question on that, then.

Comment: @Botje It may have to do with sys.path.append only changing the path in the current session. I'll look up how to permanently change sys.path. Hopefully it will work then. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you have to change that as part of your embedded code. You could for example use `PyRun_SimpleString("import sys; sys.path.append('/home/MyUserName/MyFolder')");`

Comment: @Botje Thank you very much, it appears to be working now! There was also an error due to calling  pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("EmbedTest.py") instead of  pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("EmbedTest").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning off LTO with `-fno-lto` solved it.

Comment: turning off LTO doesn't actually solve the problem...it just masks it.  It's like fixing a leaky faucet by shutting off water to the house or fixing a compilation issue by not compiling the file. I'm running into this issue, but want to leave LTO turned on for it's obvious benefits.

Comment: I assume the problem is that the python library you're linking to was built with a slightly different tool chain than your main file and that is preventing the LTO from being possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I misdirected PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR and PYTHON_LIBRARIES in my **CMakeList.txt**. The problem was solved when I removed the manual location designation.